# Is it possible in Java to add an Object to a map from the Object's constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, maps

no idea if this is possible, cant seem to find an answer online so here it goes.

I'm modeling an ad bidding platform in java, where advertisers submit offers to show ads on a site and the highest bid wins.

I created a Bid object(Which contains the price offered, ad url, and name of the bidder for tracking) and an Auction object that's really just a TreeMap of prices(as ints) and Bids (as Bid objects).

I know this is a super rudimentary look at such a thing, but is it possible to have the Bid object constructor add the Bid to the Auction? Just to stick to DRY principles? If not possible from the constructor, is there somewhere else I can automate this outside of the Main method?

Bid.class

```
public class Bid {
private int cents;
private String location;
private String bidServer;

public Bid(int cents, String location, String bidServer) {
    this.cents = cents;
    this.location = location;
    this.bidServer = bidServer;

}

public int getCents() {
    return cents;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public String getBidServer() {
    return bidServer;
}
```

}

Auction.class

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Auction {
private Map<Integer, Bid> bids ;

public Auction() {
    this.bids = new TreeMap<>();
}

public void addBid (Bid bid){
    bids.put(bid.getCents(), bid);
}

public Bid getHighestBid(){
    return bids.get(((TreeMap<Integer, Bid>) bids).lastKey());
}

public void clearBids(){
    bids.clear();
}
```

}

Comment: In order for a new `Bid` to add itself to an `Auction`, it has to be told the `Auction` to which it should add itself.  So the thing that creates the `Bid` has to know the `Auction` to which the `Bid` should add itself in order to tell the `Bid` the `Auction` to which it should add itself.  So the the thing the creates the `Bid` could just as easily add it to the appropriate `Auction` itself.  And are you sure that merely creating a `Bid` object will **always** require it to be added immediately to an `Auction`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the method `addBid` in `Auction`:

```
public void addBid(int cents, String location, String bidServer) {
    Bid bid = new Bid(cents, location, bidServer);
    bids.put(cents, bid);
}
```

You could put `Auction` and `Bid` in the same package and make the constructor of `Bid` package-private.

Also, you should declare `bids` like this:

```
private SortedMap<Integer, Bid> bids;
```

In that case you can write method `getHighestBid` like this:

```
public Bid getHighestBid() {
    return bids.get(bids.lastKey());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the `Auction` object when you construct the bid and then just add the `Bid` as `this` like so:

```
public Bid(int cents, String location, String bidServer, Auction auction) {
    this.cents = cents;
    this.location = location;
    this.bidServer = bidServer;

    auction.addBid(this);
}
```